# why is there a margin introduced at the top as I move from iPhone startup image to same image as background on UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

why is there a margin introduced as I move from iPhone startup image to same image as background on UIView?

So I have:

- image used for background/startup on iPhone, it's size is:   320 x 480
- after startup I have a UIView that displays the same image (idea is not to have any difference the user can see when transisiton from start up image to the UIView background image)
- the first view is "inside" a UINavigationController, however I set the MenuBar and Toolbar to hidden

There is however blank grey margin introduced at the top of the screen, between the signal strength bar and the top of the background image?  The height of this grey margin I wasn't expecting looks to be about the height of the top signal strength bar.  So this margin/bar effectively drops the background image downwards...

How can I remove this?

**Before (i.e. iPhone startup image)**:

[image]

**After (background image of first view)**:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found two things required to fix it:

1. setting the View Mode to "bottom" and
2. found the imageview was slightly off positioned within the XIB designer itself

Answer (score 1):

Your launch image contains an imitation of the status bar. The launch image takes up the whole 320x480, but the background image is placed at the top of the main view which is below the status bar. So you can see the imitation status bar still.

Just decrease the y of the background image view to -20.